# Changing color of only one stacked bar using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

I have a stacked bar chart made with ggplot in R (markdown). I want the stacked bar for "north" to be in a grayscale, and the other bars to stay in the color scale they currently are. I am in reality working with a lot larger data set, so the solution should preferably find where x = "north" and grayscale only that bar.

```
Region <- c("north", "south", "east", "west", "north", "south", "east", "west")
q14 <- c("5", "5", "5", "5", "4", "4", "4", "4")
N <- c(4342, 5325, 654, 1231, 3453, 234, 345, 5634)
Percentage <- c(72, 71, 68, 67, 21, 20, 18, 17)
df <- data.frame(Region, q14, N, Percentage)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Region, y = Percentage, fill = q14, label = Percentage)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#bbd6ad", "#63ab41"))
```

Super thankful for help!

I have tried tweaking scale_fill_manual without any good result, only resulting in changing the color of all bars.

Comment: Do you need the legend? If you can do without it, then code the colors manually as a new column (e.g., `df$col <- ...`) and specify as `fill = I(col)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the following

```
Region <- c("north", "south", "east", "west", "north", "south", "east", "west")
q14 <- c("5", "5", "5", "5", "4", "4", "4", "4")
N <- c(4342, 5325, 654, 1231, 3453, 234, 345, 5634)
Percentage <- c(72, 71, 68, 67, 21, 20, 18, 17)
df <- data.frame(Region, q14, N, Percentage)

df <- mutate(df,
  q14 = case_when(
    Region == "north" &
      q14 == 4 ~ "4 North",
    Region == "north" ~ "5 North",
    q14 == 4 ~ "4",
    TRUE ~ "5"
  )
)


ggplot(df, aes(
  x = Region, y = Percentage,
  fill = q14,
  label = Percentage
)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values =
      c(
        "4 North" = "#444444",
        "5 North" = "#AAAAAA",
        "4" = "#63ab41",
        "5" = "#bbd6ad"
      )
  )
```